# How to aggregate non-float values in Deedle

Tags: f#, deedle

`Frame.aggregateRowsBy` is used to perform the aggregation.
In this case, the third argument, `aggFunc`, will be an aggregate function such as `Stats.max`.
However, most of the functions defined in the `Stats` module seem to support only `float`.
How can I aggregate the maximum and minimum values as `DateTime` or `decimal`?

The following is sample code that results in a runtime error.

```ml
Frame([ "id"; "date"; "quantity"], [Series.ofValues [1; 1; 2]; Series.ofValues [ DateTime(2023, 4, 13); DateTime(2023, 4, 10); DateTime(2023, 4, 16) ]; Series.ofValues [ 2.7M; 1.2M; 1.5M; ]])
|> Frame.aggregateRowsBy ["id"] ["date"; "quantity"] Stats.max
```

```
Error: System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Double'.
```

There are two things to accomplish:

1. Aggregate non-`float` values (e.g. `DateTime`, `IComparable`)
2. The post-aggregation `Frame` should respect the value type of the pre-aggregation. (The result of the aggregation must not be a `float`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One limitation of the `aggregateRowsBy` function is that you can only use this to aggregate columns where the values can be converted to one shared type. You can always make that `obj`, but then it will be very hard to do anything useful with the values. In your case, you can actually use `IComparable`, which will let you pass the values of the series to `Seq.max`:

```
df 
|> Frame.aggregateRowsBy ["id"] ["date"; "quantity"] 
    (fun (ds:Series<_, IComparable>) -> ds.Values |> Seq.max)
```

In more complex cases, this probably won't work. Then it probably will be easier to run `aggregateRowsBy` multiple times (on different types of columns) - something like:

```
let dq = df |> Frame.aggregateRowsBy ["id"] ["quantity"] Stats.max
let dd = df |> Frame.aggregateRowsBy ["id"] ["date"] (fun (ds:Series<_, DateTime>) -> Seq.max ds.Values)
dq.AddColumn("date", dd.Columns.["date"])
dq.Print()
```

For reference, the `obj`-based version would be:

```
df |> Frame.aggregateRowsBy ["id"] ["date"; "quantity"] (fun (ds:Series<_, obj>) -> 
  let asFloat = ObjectSeries(ds).TryAs<float>() 
  if asFloat.HasValue then box (Stats.max asFloat.Value) else
  let asDt = ObjectSeries(ds).TryAs<DateTime>() 
  if asDt.HasValue then box (Seq.max (asDt.Value.Values))
  else failwith "Wrong column type!")
```

Comment: Instead of using `Stats.max` in the aggregate function part, I found that by writing `(Series.values >> Seq.max)`, I can aggregate with respect to type without explicit type annotation. This would be useful.